# Gradle not recognizing local Maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

I want to add a Maven dependency from my local Maven repository to my Gradle project.

In my *build.gradle* I have the following line to specify the use of local Maven repository:

`mavenLocal()`

However, when I want to add the dependency, Gradle does not suggest my local Maven artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the repository index has ben updated for this local repository in IDE settings:
[image]

Comment: Thank you but the list is empty in my project. Probably because it is not a Maven project but Gradle.

Comment: Okay, it was probably just a glitch in IDEA. The list is not empty now but unfortunately it did not help to solve the issue.